# AngularJS use constant in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined a constant like this:

```
app.constant('ngSettings', {
    apiBaseUrl: 'https://url/'
});
```

how can I reference now this constant in a directive?

Where the directive is something like this:

```
angular.module('my.directive', []).directive(...................
```

Comment: I believe `.directive('xxx', ['ngSettings', function(ngSettings) { ...directive definition as usual...}])` works.

Comment: not a good idea using `ng` prefix for your own components. First it makes it seem like it's part of angular core and it also opens to potential future collisions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can inject the constant anywhere that is injectable including the directive definition itself, the controller of a directive, the link function, et. al.

```
angular.module('my.directive', []).directive('name', ['ngSettings', function (ngSettings) {
    // do things with ngSettings
    return {};
}]);
```

By the way I wouldn't name anything you define yourself as `ng` -- that should be preserved for things in the `ng` module or that Angular itself created.

Comment: Ok so it was within the directive itself. I was trying to add it in the square brakets after the module name. Great! The ngSettings was just an example.

Comment: Can you declare it somehow at the module level? Let's say within the module my.directive there are 50 directives, so rather then declaring it for each directive can it be done at the module level?

Comment: You could potentially hack it that way, but I don't recommend it because you're bypassing angular's dependency injection.
If you REALLY want to, you could even define it as a regular object (or function that returns an object) globally in JS, outside of angular itself, and reference that from anywhere. That would be silly though.
It would also make unit testing difficult.

Comment: @HankScorpio: What about if I declare it's own module `angular.module('myconstants'),[].constant(blah blah)` ... and then just reference this module within other module ... like: `angular.module('my.directive'), ['myconstants']).directive(....` ? Or is the same thing you told?

Comment: That declares the `'myconstants'` module as a dependency of the `'my.directive'` module. That's one part, and you should definitely do that if they're in different modules, but you still need to invoke the constants (`ngSettings`) in every directive/controller/service or wherever you intend to use them. Explosion Pills' code does that.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you would use any other dependency.

```
angular.module('my.directive', []).directive('my', ['ngSettings', function (ngSettings) {
    ...
}]);
```

Constants are particular cases of [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

> The remaining four recipe types — Value, Factory, Service and Constant
>   — are just syntactic sugar on top of a provider recipe.